# Zend pdf text not set on rectangle

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf, zend-framework

I tried below code in my `TestController.php` but I do not understand how to put text on rectangle

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
    $page = new Zend_Pdf_Page(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
     // $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);

        $this->y -= 10;

        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

    $font = Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_HELVETICA);

    define('FONT_SIZE'      , 12);
    define('MARGIN_LEFT'    , 40);
    define('MARGIN_TOP'     , 40);
    define('COL_WIDTH'      , 100);
    define('COL_LEFT_MARGIN', 10);
    define('COL_SEPARATOR'  , '|');
    define('ROW_HEIGHT'     , 20);

    $row = 1;
    $x = MARGIN_LEFT;
    $y = MARGIN_TOP;
$linecolor = "#cccccc";
$fillcolor = "#000000";
    $page->setFont($font, FONT_SIZE);
    $page->drawText('Text on Rectangle', $x, $page->getHeight() - $y);
    $page->setFillColor(Zend_Pdf_Color_Html::color($fillcolor));
$page->setFillColor(Zend_Pdf_Color_Html::color($linecolor));
    //$page->drawRectangle(10, 50, 200, 450);
    $page->drawRectangle(25, 0, 570, $page->getHeight() - 45);

    $x += COL_WIDTH;

    $x += COL_LEFT_MARGIN;

    $x = MARGIN_LEFT;
    $y += ROW_HEIGHT;
    //echo "<pre>";
    //print_r($page->getContents());
    $pdf->pages[] = $page;
    //$pdf->save("test_{$now->getTimestamp()}.pdf");
    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse('invoice.pdf', $pdf->render(), 'application/pdf');
```

I want to similar like below image in pdf

[image]